# Can I create a Javascript chart from this table?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts

I just started programming with Highcharts, and wonder if it's possible to get any sort of line chart based on this table: http://www2.nve.no/h/hd/plotreal/Q/0027.00025.000/knekkpunkt.html

The table updates each half hour, and I want to program a line chart that updates accordingly.

My problem is that I have no idea if this is possible. The table data are remote, on a server I don't have access to. The data is public and open, though.

Would be grateful for some help!

Comment: Could you update your link, which seems to not working?

Comment: It should work, but I uploaded the data here on my server: http://fluefiske.net/dok/graf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One great open source project you'd want to check out is [D3.js](http://www.d3js.org/). It's a feature-rich library for generating complex visualizations (using SVG elements and the DOM) from raw data. Here is a demo I made using a snippet of your data that is powered by D3:

http://jsfiddle.net/2s6Y3/

```
//Define two functions that will 'map' x- and y-values into their respective axis domain
var x_scale_fn = d3.scale.linear().domain([Math.min.apply(null, times), Math.max.apply(null, times)]).range([0, width]);
var y_scale_fn = d3.scale.linear().domain([Math.max.apply(null, levels), Math.min.apply(null, levels)]).range([0, height]);

//Create a 'line' object that can read our records and turn them into x-y coordinates
var line = d3.svg.line()
.x_scale_fn(function(d, i) { return x(times[i]); })
.y_scale_fn(function(d, i) { return y(levels[i]); });

//Create a new SVG element (our chart) and give it some basic attributes
var graph = d3.select(".chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margins[1] + margins[3])
    .attr("height", height + margins[0] + margins[2])
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins[3] + ", " + margins[0] + ")");

//Create our chart axes
var x_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x),
    y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

//Render the x-axis
graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(x_axis)
    .selectAll("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(45deg)"; }); 

//Render the y-axs
graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(y_axis);

//Render our data (line) onto the chart
graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
```

If you want to create a project that offers a persistent, up-to-date visualization of the water data, you'll need to set up a scraper that will periodically read data from the page and format it to be used by D3 (i.e. - JSON). This could be done with a number of different tools, but one suggestion would be using Python and [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

Comment: Ok, this is unfortunately way over my coding skills. But then I have an idea of how to move forward, and maybe learn what I need to get this to work.

Comment: D3 code is a little strange to read if you're not familiar with the syntax (the library makes extensive use of method-chaining, as a convention), and requires some knowledge of the SVG model. I can go into more detail about any of the above code if you're curious. Still, if you think that other programmers facing a similar problem would find this helpful, please accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible, but not fun at all. That data is all one big preformatted string. Getting access to a table of those values will make things way easier for you. Otherwise, you'll need to look into writing some RegEx to parse that monster  node's text.

Comment: I see, then this is not a task for me. Glad for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your link seems to not be working.

If you are talking about an HTML table, take a look at the demo here:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

Comment: The problem is that this data updates each hour, and are hosted by someone other than me.

Comment: How often it updates is not a problem.  Whatever you create to parse this data can run each time the page loads and will always be up to date.  Is that page the *source* of the data, or is that your page on which you are displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, this made me realize that my skills doesn't add up to what it takes to get this working.